# Caching Azure-served images in the browser

Tags: azure, browser-cache, azure-blob-storage, response-headers

I have a load of images stored as blobs in an Azure container.

I am attempting to get the browser (Chrome) to cache these images to save bandwidth. I have read many posts stating that this can be achieved by setting the Cache-Control response header. I am using the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer to modify these headers, e.g:

```
public, max-age=7776000
```

[image: Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer]

When loading this image (https://XXXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/XXXXXXXX/Themes/summer.jpg) this is what I see using Google Chrome's Developer Tools:

[image: Dev Tools]

It doesn't make any difference to the caching of the image. I have tried many different permutations of the allowed `CacheControl` attributes but I don't see any caching going on at all. The status is always `200`, but I was expecting `304` for a cache hit. Is this correct?

Whichever `CacheControl` string I provide is always displayed in Chrome's results; it just doesn't seem to make any difference to the caching aspect. I've tried variations of `public`, `private`, `max-age`, `s-maxage`, `must-revalidate`. And just to be complete, `no-cache` and `no-store`. No differences were observed.

The above image takes **900ms+** to load for me. However, when saved locally, the same image takes **19ms**. I would expect if the browser was caching the image then it's timing would be equivalent to the local time.

Other posts suggest that an `Azure CDN` be used. However, I don't want to go down this route as the site that uses these images would not need that.

Am I missing a setting in Azure to allow caching? Loading the images directly in the browser, or within a web page makes no difference either.

Can anyone provide assistance? Let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: What about other browsers? Did you check the disable-cache option in chrome?

Comment: I am also not able to reproduce this issue. In fact, I am seeing exact opposite :). I had set up cache-control as `max-age=30` but I see browser responding with 304 status code even after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CacheControl` settings should take effect.

When using chrome, please make sure you didn't select the option "disable-cache".

I can see the expected behavior when set `max-age=xx` for CacheControl in chrome.

[image]